# For loop python, finding secons smallest number

Tags: python, for-loop

I created this code to enter a string of integers by a user. I am trying to write a loop to find the second smallest number in de list. How do I finish this?

```
numbers_input = raw_input('Insert numbers seperated by a space')
numbers_strings = numbers_input.split() 
numbers_list = map(int, numbers_strings)

for x in numbers_list:
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a `for` loop? Why not `heapq.nsmallest()` or a simple `sorted(numbers_list)[1]`?

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: im practicing with loops

Comment: How is asking Stack Overflow for the solution a good way to "practice"? At least be honest that this is your homework assignment and you need to use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Its what that [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) is for:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> l=[10, 12, 2, 2, 5 ,15]
>>> print(heapq.nsmallest(2, set(l))) [1]
5
```

**Note that `set(l)` is for remove duplicate indices !** (*thank of Jon Clements for reminding in comment*)

Also you can use `sorted(iterable)[:n][1]` for find **second smallest**  that `sorted(iterable)[:n]` give you n smallest indices !

The most important feature of a heap is that `heap[0]` is always the smallest item. More‐
over, subsequent items can be easily found using the `heapq.heappop()` method, which
pops off the first item and replaces it with the next smallest item (an operation that
requires O(log N) operations where N is the size of the heap)

[source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py) of `nsmallest`

```
def nsmallest(n, iterable):
    """Find the n smallest elements in a dataset.

Equivalent to:  sorted(iterable)[:n]
"""
if n < 0:
    return []
it = iter(iterable)
result = list(islice(it, n))
if not result:
    return result
_heapify_max(result)
_heappushpop = _heappushpop_max
for elem in it:
    _heappushpop(result, elem)
result.sort()
return result
```

Comment: Just to note, if you throw in another `2` to that list you'll get `2` as the second smallest number - depending on the requirements - that may not be the desired result...

Comment: @JonClements excuse me i cant figure out what you mean ?

Comment: Depends if the second lowest unique number is required...

Comment: oh , yep , thank for reminding ! so i need a `set` !